# Memory management in a custom UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm new with iOS development, but I'm familiar with the memory management basics in Obj-C. However, Apple's docs about custom UIViewControllers confused me a bit.

So, I have a `PagingController` that stores an array of `EntryViewController` objects. (They're all UIViewControllers.) These objects are loaded dynamically and, of course, released when appropriate. The view in `PagingController` is created in `-loadView` and stored in `self.view`, just as the documentation said.
Whenever I load an `EntryViewController` (as `ctrl`), I call `[self.view addSubview:ctrl.view];`. I also need to call `ctrl.parent = self;` since the target OS is 3.0 and I don't want to modify a private variable (`_parentViewController`). (`parent` is defined as `@property(assign) PagingController *parent;`)

Here are my questions:

1. Do I have to release `self.view` myself, or is UIViewController taking care of that?
2. Do I have to retain `parent` (the property in `EntryViewController`)? I assume it's pointless, since all the child view controllers are being released when the parent is unloaded.
3. Do I have to call `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` in the `-dealloc` method of `EntryViewController`? The docs said, I have to manage all of the subviews, so I'm not sure if this gets called automatically.

Or am I just confused about how to create a custom view controller in the first place?

Comment: Please share the correct answer for this question, i am also interested in knowing it

Comment: @jrturton Actually it's 3.2, but my point is that `-addChildViewController` is only available since 5.0; and I don't want to exclude 4.x users.

Comment: Does anybody know from experience whether Apple rejects apps that change `_parentViewController`?

Comment: One of the good things that addChildViewController brings is that the children automatically get the viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad etc. and orientation change method calls; but you can do this on iOS < 5 by manually forwarding these messages from your "parent" view controller, without the need to access a private Cocoa property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. UIViewController will take care of that
2. You shouldn't retain parent, set the property to assign, otherwise you're gonna have a retain cycle
3. The view controller will take care its view, you only need to release the other subviews you are retaining (removeFromSuperview isn't necessary)

Comment: Thanks! I've read about retain cycles before, and I had a suspicion that might happen here...